# Why did Simic become the preferred Nexus colors in M20?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In War of the Spark, [Bant Nexus was a legitimate deck](http://www.starcitygames.com/articles/38645_Bant-Nexus-Is-The-Better-Nexus-Of-Fate-Deck.html). That's not to say Simic Nexus was not a competitive deck, and in fact Mattias Leveratto [won Mythic Championship III with it](https://www.mtggoldfish.com/deck/2020099#paper), but Bant was a real variant.

However in M20 it's become clear that Simic is now the dominant Nexus colors. Why?

- Did Teferi, Hero of Dominaria become less powerful as a win con? If so, why?
- Did Simic gain some great new cards that cover the same bases as the white cards, which rendered them not worth it?
- Did the meta shift in a way that made the white cards less important?

For comparison M20 Simic lists [look like this](https://www.mtggoldfish.com/deck/2157102#paper). The differences are the win con (Simic generally runs [Callous Dismissal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCallous%20Dismissal%5d), which is more versatile when you're not comboing, but is slow enough that [Chandra, Awakened Inferno](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20Awakened%20Inferno%5d)'s emblem is deadly, and narrow enough that you can't beat [Unmoored Ego](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnmoored%20Ego%5d) naming Nexus), mana base, and sideboard.